# Extract one specific column with blank lines from multiple csv files and merge into one

Tags: python, r, pandas, loops, csv

I have my csv files in the same folder. I want to get only the data in the 5th column from all my csv files and write the data into a single file. But there are blank lines in my csv files. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SospIppACOrLeKPU_9OknnDLnDpatIqE/view?usp=sharing

How can I keep the blanks with pandas.read_csv command?

Many thanks!

Comment: This was put on hold for the wrong reason. It's not too broad, I think the explanation is quite clear. It's not a great question, though, in that it provides no examples, no sample code. But that is not unclear, it's just under-justified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `usecols` argument of `pandas.read_csv`.

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
```

So what we are doing here is that we are looping over all files in the current directory that end with `.csv` and then for each of those files only read in the column of interest, i.e. the 5th column. We write `usecols=[4]` because pandas uses 0-based indexing, so out of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, the fifth number is 4. Additionally you asked to skip blank lines and your sample data contains 9 blank lines leading up to actual data, so we will set `skiprows` to 9.
We concatenate all of those into one DataFrame using `pd.concat`.

```
combined_df = pd.concat(
                        [
                         pd.read_csv(csv_file, usecols=[4], skiprows=9) 
                         for csv_file in glob('*.csv')
                         ]
                        )
```

To get rid of blank lines from your DataFrame, you can simply use:

```
combined_df = combined_df.dropna()
```

This `combined_df` we can then simply write to file:

```
combined_df.to_csv('combined_column_5.csv')
```

Comment: Hello thank you very much for your help. But I have a stupid question. There is an error says "No objects to concatenate". Is it because I should replace csv_file in the pd.read_csv function by my csv file names?  Thanks!

Comment: Ok I think I figure out this problem. But there is another error now. It says "Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found". Do you mind telling me how to solve it?

Comment: You have to change the name of column_of_interest to the name of that column in your csv but let me make an edit that should make this unnecessary

Comment: There, take a look again now!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It is very clear. And the code works with my other csv files. But it is my fault. I wasn't so clear. I have a file like this with blank lines. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10V4s4QmeO3tFvArUYju6rlUI78-owVPO?usp=sharing. And I only want the 5th column while keeping all the blanks. Do you mind having a look and giving me some hints? Thank you soooo much!

Comment: You can just set the `skiprows` keyword argumant to `9`, as it seems you don't want the first 9 lines. As for the rest of the spreadsheet, I would advise you to just filter those lines you don't want out after reading them in. You can get rid of empty lines by using `combined_df =  combined_df.dropna()` and you can use pd.replace to replace the `(Year-to-date)` rows.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now! Thank you for your patience!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! For future reference - the [`pandas documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) is really good, you can find a lot of examples there!

Answer (score 1):

Fake data:

```
sapply(1:3, function(i) write.csv(mtcars, paste0(i,".csv"), row.names=FALSE))
```

results in three csv files, named `1.csv` through `3.csv`, each with:

```
"mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb"
21,6,160,110,3.9,2.62,16.46,0,1,4,4
21,6,160,110,3.9,2.875,17.02,0,1,4,4
22.8,4,108,93,3.85,2.32,18.61,1,1,4,1
21.4,6,258,110,3.08,3.215,19.44,1,0,3,1
...
```

The code:

```
write.csv(sapply(list.files(pattern="*.csv"), function(a) read.csv(a)[,5]),
          "agg.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

results in a single CSV file, `agg.csv`, that contains

```
"1.csv","2.csv","3.csv"
3.9,3.9,3.9
3.9,3.9,3.9
3.85,3.85,3.85
3.08,3.08,3.08
...
```